# run stats linear regression on all dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a list of x and y coordinates. I'm trying ot run a stats linear regression function on it, but it's giving me nan's in the whole thing.

The dataframe looks like this

```
  x1  x2  x3  x4  y1  y2  y3  y4 
0 6   5   4   1   2   3   7   6 
1 5   5   4   9   4   3   8   2
```

and my code looks like this:

```
#slope,_,_,_,_=stats.linregress([-7,55,12,-38],[5,40,-10,-20]) #tested:works 

df.loc[:,'slope1'] = df[['x1','x2','y1','y2']].apply(lambda x: stats.linregress([x[0],x[1]],[x[2],x[3]])[0])
df.loc[:,'slope2'] = df[['x3','x4','y3','y4']].apply(lambda x: stats.linregress([x[0],x[1]],[x[2],x[3]])[0])

# not working until linregress above works:
#df['angle'] = np.arctan((df['slope1'] - df['slope2']) / (1 + (df['slope1'] * df['slope2'])))
```

this produces:

```
  x1  x2  x3  x4  y1  y2  y3  y4  slope1  slope2 
0 6   5   4   1   2   3   7   6   NaN     NaN  
1 5   5   4   9   4   3   8   2   NaN     NaN
```

How am I supposed to apply a function to a dataframe column so that it gives something other than nan?

Comment: Show us your expected results so we can make sure we understand what regression you're trying to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need define `axis=1` for processes function per rows:

```
from scipy import stats

f = lambda x: stats.linregress([x[0],x[1]],[x[2],x[3]])[0]
df['slope1'] = df[['x1','x2','y1','y2']].apply(f, axis=1)
df['slope2'] = df[['x3','x4','y3','y4']].apply(f, axis=1)

df['angle'] = np.arctan((df['slope1'] - df['slope2']) / (1 + (df['slope1'] * df['slope2'])))
print (df)
   x1  x2  x3  x4  y1  y2  y3  y4  slope1    slope2     angle
0   6   5   4   1   2   3   7   6    -1.0  0.333333 -1.107149
1   5   5   4   9   4   3   8   2     NaN -1.200000       NaN
```